# integrate Azure alerts with Zendesk ticketing system

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, zendesk, azure-alerts

We are planning to integrate azure alerts with Zendesk, So when ever alert triggered in azure then we need to raise the ticket in Zendesk with all the details.

## what we trying now

1. There is a direct option to call webhook in action groups but we have 2 problems

   > There should be some kind of authentication before calling a webhook
   > Not found a way to exclude unwanted data from the alert, we need to pass only required
   > information to Zendesk
2. Exploring via logic apps there is a connector already available(Testing that now)

Any ideas on this will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few workarounds you can try

**WAY - 1**

> There should be some kind of authentication before calling a webhook

For this in the webhook connector when you go for Add parameters you will find the subscribe and Unsubscribe Authentications.

[image]

> Not found a way to exclude unwanted data from the alert, we need to pass only required information to Zendesk

For this, you can parse the data and then the required data using the `Compose` connector to the Zendesk. Here is the screenshot of the Logic App :-

[image]

Then you can follow the steps from [Implementing solution powered by Zendesk and Azure Logic Apps.](https://dev.to/wolksoftware/implementing-a-low-code-customer-support-solution-powered-by-zendesk-and-azure-logic-apps-52dn)

**WAY - 2**

Another workaround you can try is to download the alerts CSV file then upload the same to Blob Storage or Sharepoint, parse CSV file using `Parse CSV` Connector and then follow the same steps from [Implementing solution powered by Zendesk and Azure Logic Apps.](https://dev.to/wolksoftware/implementing-a-low-code-customer-support-solution-powered-by-zendesk-and-azure-logic-apps-52dn)

[image]